# Which spark MLIB algorithm to use?

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark

I'm newbie to machine learning and would like to understand what algorithm (Classification algorithm or co-relation algorithm?) to use in order to understand what is the relationship between one or more attributes.

for example consider I have following set of attributes,

```
Bill No, Bill Amount, Tip amount, Waiter Name
```

and would like to figure out which are the attribute(s) that are contributing to Tip amount.

Following is the sample set of data,

```
Bill No, Bill Amount, Tip amount, Waiter detail
   1,         100,          10,        Sathish
   2,         200,          20,        Sathish
   3,         150,          10,        Rahul
   4,         200,          10,        Simon
   5,         100,          10,        Sathish
```

In this case we know the Tip amount would be 99% influenced by the Bill Amount. But i want to know what is the Spark MLib algorithm that i should use to figure out the same? If so i could apply the similar techniques to long set of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is calculate correlation between rows. Take a look at the tutorial about [summary statistics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/mllib-statistics.html) at mllib website.

More advanced approach would be use [dimensionality reduction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html). This should discover more complex dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the correlation between different rows. Please refer to ***Correlations***(https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html#correlations). For example, if you calculate the correlation between Bill Amount and Tip amount, most probably you will get the correlation value near to 1.